# Can't create migrations using MikroORM and NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, mikro-orm

Unable to create migrations, or any other MikroORM CLI command, due to an unexpected error with the configuration file.

This is the current versions of MikroORM and NestJS being used on my package.json

```
"@mikro-orm/core": "^5.5.3",
"@mikro-orm/mysql": "^5.5.3",
"@mikro-orm/nestjs": "^5.1.2",
"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
"@mikro-orm/cli": "^5.5.3",
"@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
```

The MikroORM CLI was configured in the `package.json` to use `ts-node`, according to the official documentation

```
"mikro-orm": {
  "useTsNode": true,
  "configPaths": [
    "./src/config/mikro-orm.config.ts",
    "./dist/config/mikro-orm.config.js"
  ]
}
```

And this is my `mikro-orm-config.ts` file

```
export const mikroOrmConfig: Options = {
  type: 'mysql',
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  dbName: 'market_store',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'admin',
  entities: ['dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  entitiesTs: ['src/**/*.entity.ts'],
  migrations: {
    path: 'dist/migrations',
    pathTs: 'src/migrations',
  },
};
```

As you can see, the `type` was specified, but when I run any MikroORM CLI command I get the following error displayed

```
Error: No platform type specified, please fill in `type` or provide custom driver class in `driver` option. Available platforms types: [
  'mongo',
  'mysql',
  'mariadb',
  'postgresql',
  'sqlite',
  'better-sqlite'
]
```

The following is the output of my `npx mikro-orm debug` command

```
Current MikroORM CLI configuration
 - dependencies:    
   - mikro-orm 5.5.3
   - node 18.12.1   
   - typescript 4.9.3
 - package.json found                                                                              
 - ts-node enabled                                                                                 
 - searched config paths:                                                                          
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/src/config/mikro-orm.config.ts (found) 
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/dist/config/mikro-orm.config.js (found)
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/src/mikro-orm.config.ts (not found)    
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/mikro-orm.config.ts (not found)        
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/dist/mikro-orm.config.js (not found)   
   - C:/Users/DanielMendesSechisnk/Projects/nestjs-rest-api/mikro-orm.config.js (not found)        
- configuration not found (No platform type specified, please fill in `type` or provide custom driver class in `driver` option. Available platforms types: [
  'mongo',
  'mysql',
  'mariadb',
  'postgresql',
  'sqlite',
  'better-sqlite'
])
```

I created my entities manually on my database to see if the app was able to connect to the database outside of the MikroORM CLI, and it succeeded, I was able to to do several CRUD operations on my database, with it correctly being updated.

I even tried to use a lower version of MikroORM, like 5.0.3, since the official documentation has a working example using it, but the same error persisted.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use default export in your config file.

Comment: Wow, that's such a small detail, it solved my problem, thank you for noticing and taking your time to respond